# Issue with formulating a url php / html

Tags: php, html, url

I am trying to formulate a link to another page in my directory. It can either be done in the php code or the html. However for some strange reason, and only on this page, everytime i generate a url to a new page, the url generated is the page i am on + the url i want to go to.

For example, if i am on mysite.php and formulate a link to go to purchase.php then the generated url is mysite.php/purchase.php

Does anyone know why this might be?

```
<h1>Success</h1>
<a href="page.php">Link text</a>
<?php
   ...
   ...
?>
```

this is essentially all i have with an echo saying hi! . What happens is, if i am currently on home.php the above url becomes `path/home.php/page.php`

Comment: Talk to us in code, that's what we understand!

Comment: the issue is all with an html href or conversely an echoed href though  :) do you want to see one of those?!

Comment: We want to see all the parts of the code that you, as a scripter, think are related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should create url for `/purchase.php` instead of `purchase.php`.
You can read more about what's the difference in [here](http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html).